# Websphere heap size 4GB. Will memory exceed heap running two threads each consuming 3 GB memory in parallel or will websphere pause one thread?

Tags: jvm, websphere, heap-memory

Sorry for the vagueness, but I'm just trying to understand websphere memory management at a high level.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a question about JVM behavior.  As far as I know, there are no JVMs that will block a thread waiting for another thread to finish if it is holding a large amount of memory.  I expect both threads to continuously consume memory, and if both are able to allocate memory at the same rate, I would expect them both to get OutOfMemoryError as soon as their combined allocations exceed the max heap size.